# How to finish specific activities not all activities

Tags: android, android-intent

In my android application suppose several activities are there
if using intent I go to other activities like this

**[Activity A]->[activity B]->[Activity C]->[Activity-D]->[Activity N]**

and now when am on activity N when I pressed button then I want to go to **Activity B** and want to destroy Activity C And Activity D but **Activity A** should not destroy. I also searched in various posts but I didn't get exactly the same solution.
Any help will be appriciated

Comment: when you go to another activity finish that activity for example you don't want to finish activity A and Activity B then finish Activity C and Activity D

Comment: @DaminiMehra i don't want activity B and C to be finished through intent

Comment: Why you are not want to finish?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In `ActivityN`, to return to `ActivityB` use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Using the flag `CLEAR_TOP` will finish all activities in the stack that are on top of `ActivityB`. In the example you gave, this will finish `ActivityN`, `ActivityD` and `ActivityC`. Using the flag `SINGLE_TOP` will make sure that this will return control to the existing instance of `ActivityB` (ie: it won't create a new instance of `ActivityB`).

Answer (score 4):

In Your Activity C do like this

```
public static ActivityC instance = null;
public class ActivityC extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

And in your Activity D do like this

```
public static ActivityD instance = null;
public class ActivityD extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

Finally in your Activity N. Do Something like this

```
public class ActivityN extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button yourButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
         yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ActivityC.instance.finish();
                Activityd.instance.finish();
                finish();  
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i will not prefer to use **statics**.

Comment: Sometimes wired requirement force us to do static @janki gadhiya

Comment: This solution is ok, but if we have 15-20 activities then we have to create all activities intance and finish all together.

Comment: Yes. You should do

Comment: This is a horrible solution :-( Android provides `Intent` flags to do exactly what OP wants. Your solution creates memory leaks in the application because the `Activity` instances stored in the static variables can never be garbage collected. Not only that, this solution is difficult to understand and difficult to maintain. There is no reason for such a hack.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my approach.

From `Activity A`, don't just start the `Activity B`, call `startActivityForResult()` method. Do this for all subsequent calls.

Now, when you press the button from `Activity N`, set the `result` for a custom value and call the `finish()` method for `Activity N`. Now you should hit the `onActivityResult` method on your `Activity D`. Now you can check whether the result was you pressing the button. Depending on your result, keep on setting the result and subsequently calling `finish()` on each `Activity`.

This should technically work.

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT : Use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity()

So **depending on the result you can change the behavour**.

Say for example When you wanted to go to ActivityB just return some flag in the INTENT. When it will be caught in Activity D and C in **onActivityResult()**, finish them and you will be finally on **B**.

Comment: There are many views in my Activity N and i don't want to go activity B using intent there are many cases like if i back press i want to go to activity D not B so in this case finish method not works

Comment: thanks for this solution and Flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP also solved my problem

Comment: complete concept is in this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:
 //Activity A

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext,ActvityB.class);
startActivity(i);
```

//Activity B

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext,ActvityC.class);
startActivity(i);
```

//Activity C

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext,ActvityC.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();  
// finish here actvity which you want to finish
```

//Try this second way:

In your first activity, declare one Activity object like this,

```
public static Activity fa;
onCreate()
{
 fa = this;
}
```

now use that object in another Activity to finish first-activity like this,

```
onCreate()
{
 FirstActivity.fa.finish();
}
```

Comment: Using back press i want to go previous activity from which intent is fired so , i want to go activity B on special case that's why i don't want to use finish method.

Comment: This is a horrible solution :-( Android provides `Intent` flags to do exactly what OP wants. Your solution creates memory leaks in the application because the `Activity` instances stored in the static variables can never be garbage collected. Not only that, this solution is difficult to understand and difficult to maintain. There is no reason for such a hack.

Answer (score 1):

Flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP may solve your problem:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Answer (score 0):

You can start `ActivityC`, `ActivityD`, `ActivityN` with the same request code passed to `startForResult(requestCode)`

And then at ActivityN, use `finishActivity(int requestCode)`.

Documentation for `finishActivity(int requestCode)`

```
Force finish another activity that you had previously started with startActivityForResult.
Params:
requestCode – The request code of the activity that you had given to startActivityForResult().
If there are multiple activities started with this request code, they will all be finished.
```